# Update a varible in list using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a disks variable as a list

```
disks:
  - gb: 17.00
    type: flat
    number: 12
  - gb: 16.00
    type: flat
    number: 12
```

I wanted to convert all the gb to int, ie. 16 and 17.

```
- name: Update size
  set_fact:
   disks: "{{ disks | map('combine', {'gb': item.gb| float | round(0, 'common') | int }) | list }}"
  loop: "{{ disks }}"
```

I tried as above, but both the gb is converted to the last value 16.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#examples).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    disks:
      - gb: 17.00
        type: flat
        number: 12
      - gb: 16.00
        type: flat
        number: 12

  tasks:

  # Update an existing fact, dot notation
  - name: Update the fact
    ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: disks.0.gb
          value: "{{ disks.0.gb | float | round(0, 'common') | int }}"
        - path: disks.1.gb
          value: "{{ disks.1.gb | float | round(0, 'common') | int }}"
    register: updated

  - debug:
      var: updated.disks
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  updated.disks:
  - gb: '17'
    number: 12
    type: flat
  - gb: '16'
    number: 12
    type: flat
```

A tasks with [`loop` and added controls](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops)

```yaml
  # Update an existing fact, bracket notation
  - name: Update the fact
    ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: "disks.{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}.gb"
          value: "{{ disks[ansible_loop.index0].gb | float | round(0, 'common') | int }}"
    register: updated
    loop: "{{ range(0, (disks | length), 1) }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

  - debug:
      var: (updated.results | last).disks
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  (updated.results | last).disks:
  - gb: '17'
    number: 12
    type: flat
  - gb: '16'
    number: 12
    type: flat
```

---

Other possibilities with [Selecting values from arrays or hashtables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) like `disks | map(attribute='gb') | list` are shown in example under [Ansible: How to change a value inside a dictonary list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050919/6771046)

For both approaches take note that Ansible do not update variables (a.k.a facts) in place but return new result sets.

Comment: Thank you, but I cant manually update each list. It is being passed from another job. I would like to know the single code to update all the values in the list.

Comment: That's trivial. One need only to adopt the given example. I've shown an example with a loop over the list.

Comment: As you can see from my minimal reproducible example with provided input, processing and output, there is no such error.